# How connect Azure Storage Explorer to Azurite running in WSL?

Tags: azure-storage, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azurite

On Windows 10, I have Azurite running on Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL 2. However, I can not connect to it via the Azure Storage Manager installed on Windows 10.

### What I tried

I tried setting up a connection in the Storage Explorer via *Local Azure Storage Emulator*. However, I get an error that there is no Emulator installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there Azurite must be **running** while one adds a *Local Storage Emulator* within the Storage Explorer. Therefore, simply make sure that Azurite is running and the Storage Explorer will recognize it, despite Azurite running within WSL. (Not my proudest question, still leaving it in case anyone else has the same issue.)